# Работа с указателями в С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Извините за глупый вопрос, но я только начал осваивать С++.Нашел в интернете код, где написана строка, но так и не смог понять, что она означает. Можете пояснить, пожалуйста.

```
Stad *node = new Stad;
Stad *nodet(node);
```

Конкретно интересует, что делает вторая строка?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Stad *nodet(node);
```

означает ровно то же самое, что и

```
Stad *nodet = node;
```

По сути, вы получаете два указателя с одинаковыми значениями, указывающие на один и тот же объект типа `Stad`.

Comment: А какая запись будет более корректной или нет разницы?

Comment: @walde Именно в этом случае разница только в стиле. Запись со скобками чаще используется для классов, а с указателями лично для меня выглядит непривычно. Я бы писал через `=`. Но тут уж как вам больше нравится; некоторые вообще пишут `Stad *nodet{node};`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. В примере и шла речь о классе.

Comment: @walde Нет, я о том, что `nodet` - не класс, а указатель (пусть и на класс).

Comment: Если разобрались, жмякните на галочку слева от ответа, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный...

Comment: Не факт, что означает именно это. Если где-то до этого есть объявление типа `node` то эта строка объявляет функцию. Именно поэтому запись с присваиванием будет более корректной.